# Joomla, static text after every article

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

Is there anyone who knows how to add piece of code under every article of joomla. Joomla version 1.5.
Whitch files I should edit or maybe theres some plugin or component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one other way can be in template you override the view of com_content and add some static text in there. Simple thing you can try is go to 
`\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\ pick default.php` from there and put it in `templates\template_name\html\com_content\article\`

now here change the default.php to contain that static text.

Comment: Hi, I think what you say is fine too, but the path to override the template should be: templates\template_name\html\com_content\article\tmpl\

Answer (score 4):

You can create a system/content plugin
which should work on `onPrepareContent` trigger

```
function onPrepareContent($item, $params, $limitstart)
{
   // append text in $item->text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need some text/html *(not php code)*, than you can use this plugin: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/articles-styling/7404
 - it has a lot of configuration options